# Hijri bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, calendar, hijri

I am currently using `bootstrap-datepicker.js` for generating the calendar in `en`. How can extend it for the `Hijri Calendar`?

bootstrap provide the localization but how complete Hijri calendar can be generated?

Answer (score 0):

Hi for a localised "angular" calendar you typically need the following:

- the angular bootstrap datepicker (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)
- the hijri locale file from https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.3/i18n/
- script reference to hijri locale file from web root html page e.g. in index.html:

```html
<script src="i18n/angular-locale_ar.js"></script>
```

- setting angular locale progarmmatically to hijri e.g.

```js
    angular.module('app')
        .config(['$locale', function($locale){
          $locale.id = "ar";
        }])
```

Though this answer refers to the angular approach, the pattern is most likely shared by other frameworks :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can get UmmAlqura calendar which is similar to hijri with Bootstrap.
https://github.com/fesksa/bootstrap-calendars.
This might help you in getting the hijri date picker.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the latest version of [Tempus Dominus](https://github.com/Eonasdan/tempus-dominus). this would help you to build the calendar in a correct way. to convert the date, you could use `Intl` ([read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl)) as following:

```js
a = new Date();
localeFormat= 'ar-SA-islamic-umalqura';
Intl.DateTimeFormat(localeFormat).format(a)
```